# How do I compile IPA files on Windows?

Tags: development-environment, ipa

I recently have been wanting to compile IPA files on windows but I have not found any solutions. Apple says you can only compile on Mac. But I disagree, because you can compile on other operating systems, even mobile operating systems. I know an app that will compile IPA files on iOS. So I call that 'mac only' thing a myth.
I've tried getting into something like MobiOne, but that does not compile IPA files, it makes a web app. I've tried Xamarin, but there's a hidden page I found by Google on their website that says you can not make iOS apps on Windows with Xamarin. So how do you compile an iOS app on Windows? There has to be a way, if other operating systems can do it, why not Windows?

Comment: Read http://www.monologues.co.uk/Parodies/It_Couldnt_Be_Done.htm, as it is entirely appropriate.

Comment: I very much disagree, it CAN be done. I know people who have compiled on Windows, and they won't tell me how...

Answer (score -2):

With Adobe AIR. (Using Flash, Flash builder, Flash Develop, IntelliJ Idea) and you can add ANE for more complexity.